# Recursively menu build in php

Tags: php

I have stored my menu like as below.

```
id      label    link            parent  
------  -------  --------------  --------
    10  Home     http://cms.dev  10      
    11  About    http://about    11      
    12  History  http://history  11      
    13  Mission  http://mission  11      
    14  Contact  http://contact  14
```

How can i generate **ul** html menu recursively from the table for unlimited item.

```
Home
About
  History
  Mission
Contact
```

Comment: You should elaborate on "like as below". What does that mean? In a text file?

Comment: Look into tree builders

Comment: Pls show what have you tried and what problem you face.

Comment: I can easily build when i put the parent item as 0, but when i tried to put the parent item corresponding to it's id,it is looping....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is recursive function? Is when function calls itself.

In your case, items of every node looks as recursive structure. Yes, you have tree and tree may bypass in recursive maner.

So, do it recursively. For example, if you have plain array `$menu` with items:

```
$menu = [
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'label' => 'Home',
        'link' => 'http://cms.dev',
        'parent' => 10,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 11,
        'label' => 'About',
        'link' => 'http://about',
        'parent' => 11,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 12,
        'label' => 'History',
        'link' => 'http://history',
        'parent' => 11,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 13,
        'label' => 'Mission',
        'link' => 'http://mission',
        'parent' => 11,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 14,
        'label' => 'Contact',
        'link' => 'http://contact',
        'parent' => 14,
    ],
];
```

You may use function for menu output:

```
function echoMenu(&$menu, $parentId = null)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($menu as &$item) {
        if ((!$parentId && $item['id'] == $item['parent']) 
            || ($item['parent'] == $parentId && $item['id'] != $item['parent'])) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo "<a href=\"${item['link']}\">${item['label']}</a>";

            // Here is recursive call of echoMenu()
            echoMenu($menu, $item['id']);

            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

echoMenu($menu);
```

And I pay your etantion what it is more handy to use `'parent' => null` declarations for your root nodes. Then condition in recursive function will be more simple:

```
        if ($item['parent'] == $parentId) {
```